# Why Google crawler finds several url that is not in my page?

Tags: web-crawler, http-status-code-404, google-crawlers

I have a page that contains many url in its. This urls generate dynamically from datebase.
When I used Goggle webmaster tools for check my site, I found that one of url in database has syntax error and webmaster tools give me 404 (not found) error. As a result I fixed that error.
After that day, Goggle still gives me the same message (not found error).
Why is this happening and to fix the problem, what I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Just wait. G will crawl your page again in a few days. After that, probably the issue will be resolved.

Comment: I've waited for three weeks. But this error is repeated every day.Do I still have to wait?

Comment: As an option, try to resubmit your sitemap, as well as use Remove URLs tool to remove the 404-page from index.